# Place figure to the right of other content in beamer itemization

Tags: beamer, floats, itemize, columns

I want an itemization where one item has an equation first and then a small figure right to it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
         \begin{columns}
                \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
                    Test
                     \begin{equation*}
                     1=1
                     \end{equation*}
                \end{column}
                \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
                     \includegraphics{test.png}
                \end{column}
         \end{columns}
        \item Test
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work however. The content is displayed before the itemization bullet.

[image]

(If I omit the columns altogether, the figure is displayed after the equation instead of right of it)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the graphic in the tag:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item
           Test 
                     \begin{equation*}
                     1=1         \tag*{\raisebox{-0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}}
                     \end{equation*}
        \item Test
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the creativity but in my non MWE the equation is really a custom block with an equation inside.

Comment: I guess I could see if I can add a tag there as well,but I would also be happy with a general approach.

Comment: You can still use the raisebox idea: Put the graphic somewhere so that the vertical placement is correct and then move it up or down.

Answer (score 1):

An option is with `textblock`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage\[absolute,overlay\]{textpos}    % For text positioning

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Test 1%
\begin{equation*}
    1 = 1
\end{equation*}
        \item Test 2
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{textblock}{3}(10,7)%
        \centering
        \includegraphics\[width=0.7\linewidth\]{example-image-a}
    \end{textblock}    

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bananach, has this answer helped you? Can you accept an answer?